# Redis и "пространства имен"

Tags: php, redis

Есть идея хранить в одной базе данных редиса различные данные (например онлайн пользователей и новости). Для онлайн пользователей хочу использовать тип данных Хеш-таблицы. Условные пользователи Ваня и Петя будут выглядеть так:

```
hmset user:1 name Vasya email vasya@mail.ru
hmset user:2 name Petya email petya@mail.ru
```

1 и 2 в данном случае это их ID из основной базы данных (MySQL). В данном случае я могу легко получить значения имени и почты пользователя обратившись по полному ключу `hgetall user:1`

А что делать, если мне потребуется получить всех пользователей? Особенно если у меня есть аналогичные записи для новостей (напр. news:1 news:2 и т.д.).

Слышал, что для таких целей лучше всего использовать отдельные БД редиса, для того, чтобы случайно не перезаписать данные, но меня интересует возможность именно такой как я описал реализации. Возможно ли? И еще. При создании каждого такого ключа как user:1 я планирую использовать EXPIRE. Если кто-то решал подобную задачу - опишитесь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать set, либо sorted set, и извлекать все его значения через [zrange -inf, +inf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11505288/696034)

Учтите что Redis - это по сути key-value хранилище с расширенными возможностями и сущностями для хранения, и для запросов типа SQL оно малопригодно. Да и строить хаки ради мнимой скорости вместо удобства это занятие на любителя, либо упёртого «энтузиаста».